# Simultaneous animation with JS

Tags: javascript, animation, velocity.js

I'm trying to animate the translateX and and rotateZ attributes of an element using velocity.js, here is my code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("div").velocity({
        rotateZ: '-10deg'
    }, {
        loop: true
    });
    $("div").velocity({
        'translateX': '2000px'
    });
});
```

What I'm trying to achieve is to let the element move to the right in a straight line while always vibrating up and down (rotating 10 degrees infinitely), but the result is that the loop applies on the two attributes not only on the the rotation, and then the rotation gets bigger once the translation starts.

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/rx0ov540/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rather than using a single element and apply two animations two it, how about creating two elements and applying one animation to each.

I'd consider the following alternative:

```
<div class="outer">
    <div class="inner">I'm trying to vibrate and move.</div>
</div>
```

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".outer").velocity({
        rotateZ: '-10deg'
    }, {
        loop: true
    });
    $(".inner").velocity({
        'translateX': '2000px'
    });
});
```

Comment: That works when using divs but not svg elements, which is my case.

Comment: Why does it not work with SVG elements? You can always add additional groups into your SVG markup and id/class those.

Comment: Thank you very much. I was about to comment that I've added the element inside an svg group and translated the group and it worked as I want. :)

Comment: Good news, happy animating! :)